# Geometric meaning of localization at $(1+I)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, intuition, localization

Let $I\vartriangleleft A$ be an ideal of a commutative ring. Consider the submonoid $1+I\subset A$. What is the geometric interpretation of localization at this submonoid? How does it relate to the quotient $A/I$?

[I asked this on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230624/geometric-meaning-of-localization-at-1i) and received some interesting comments, but I would still like to know the big picture and perhaps some examples. Taking e.g $\langle x\rangle\vartriangleleft A[x]$, the localization $A[x]_{1+\langle x\rangle}$ seems like it takes $x$ to something "very infinitesimal". I don't recognize this ring as the functions on some familiar "space" as e.g the dual numbers are the functions on an infinitesimal line segment. What is the idea here?

**Added.** I thought about viewing the localization as a subring of the ring of formal power series comprised of the polynomials along with "some" power series, namely those of the form $\sum_k x^k f^k=(1-xf)^{-1}$. Don't really know where to go from here though. I also received the observation that $A[x]_{1+\langle x\rangle}$ inverts the polynomials whose value at zero is invertible, which remains true in the multivariate case. Still I wonder how to interpret the case of a general ideal.

Comment: It is the global section of the inverse image of $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}(A)}$ along the inclusion $V(I)\to\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. I don't know whether it is geometric enough. By the way, could you please include the link to the MSE post?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the scheme you obtain is the intersection of all open subsets containing $V(I)$ (since $f$ is invertible in the localization iff $(f)+I=1$ iff $D(f)\supseteq V(I)$). I think this is as geometric as it gets